# Is there a way to use the cut command in BASH to print specific columns but with characters?

Tags: bash, shell

I know I can use -f1 to print a column, but is there a way for the cut to look through columns for a specific string and print out that column?

Comment: What do you mean by "look through columns for a specific string"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Suppose I have a CSV file with several columns. I want to get a column that has a header Color. I can I get only that column without having to go through the headers and count out the column of the color column.

Comment: Consider using an actual parser. cut won't work with quoted rows.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Really sounds like a job for awk.  It would help if you gave a more complete description of what you want, along with sample input/output.

Comment: wrt `can I get only that column without having to go through the headers and count out the column of the color column.` - no, to be able to map a column name from a header to its position in each row, a tool must read the headers. Some tools can do that for you given some libraries (e.g I think python has a library for that) but the tool still has to do it and you won't have to write noticably less code, nor will it be any more efficient than just doing a loop in awk like [@WilliamPursell shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016982/1745001). It would be more robust given a more complicated CSV

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear if this is what you're looking for, but:

```
$ cat input
Length,Color,Height,Weight,Size
1,2,1,4,5
7,7,1,7,7
$ awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF+1;i++) if($i==h) break; next} {print $i}' h=Color FS=, input
2
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the colum no by a small function like this:

```
function select_column() {
    file="$1"
    sep="$2"
    col_name="$3"
    # get the separators before the field:
    separators=$(head -n 1 "${file}" | sed -e"s/\(.*${sep}\|^\)${col_name}\(${sep}.*\|$\)/\1/g" | tr -d -c ",")
    # add one, because before the n-th fields there are n-1 separators
    ((field_no=${#separators}+1))
    # now just call cut and skip the first row by using tail -n +2
    cut -d "${sep}" -f ${field_no} "${file}" | tail -n +2
}
```

When called with:

```
select_column testfile.csv "," subno
```

it outputs:

```
10
76
55
83
30
53
67
25
52
16
57
86
2
75
28
```

on the following `testfile.csv`:

```
rand2,no,subno,rand1
john,8017610,10,96
ringo,5673276,76,42
ringo,9260555,55,19
john,7565683,83,72
ringo,8833230,30,35
paul,1571553,53,55
john,9972467,67,80
ringo,922025,25,88
paul,9908052,52,1
john,6264216,16,19
paul,4350857,57,3
paul,7253386,86,50
john,3426002,2,57
ringo,1437775,75,85
paul,4384228,28,77
```